# Do you need to refresh pages after a while to continue getting live updates?

Tags: support, live-refresh

You get live updates on question pages for things like comments, answers, edits, upvotes and etc.

Do these updates/notifications stop after a while, so that you need to refresh (`F5`) the page to continue receiving them? (i.e. something like a session timeout for the live notification.) 
Or do these notifications just continue "forever" as long as the page is open?

Comment: @Louis Yes, how to reopen?

Comment: @lxg You comment in question, someone's replying to you, then you can see the comment without actually pressing `F5` to see. At the moment s\he comments you see it. It's like live mode.

Comment: @Louis You comment in question, someone's replying to you, then you can see the comment without actually pressing F5 to see. At the moment s\he comments you see it. It's like live mode.

Comment: @Louis It will reopen by itself? Or I need higher rep to have thing option?

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: The question will be automatically be proposed for reopening as soon as a substantial edit has been made.

Comment: @LyingOnTheSky: I rephrased your question based on how I understood what you were asking. If I mis-understood, please roll back the edit.

Comment: @Louis This is activity too, then yes. But I mean everything from comments to answers to edits. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no need to refresh your pages. Live updates are made possible by a web socket connection. The web socket is opened and remains open for as long as you keep open your browser page.

If updates stop after a while, something is closing the web socket for you. That could be something local on your network (a firewall perhaps) not liking long-running TCP/IP sockets and closing them forcibly. You'd have to talk to your local network administration or ISP.

You can test if your browser and network support websockets properly by using an online tester, such as http://websocketstest.com/

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to make it web-question, I thought there was specific timeout for this site.

Comment: How come it is `http://stackoverflow/questions/tagged/java` and not `ws://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java` if it is a websocket?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow/questions/tagged/java` is not a web socket. It *uses* a web socket to load updates, but that's not the same thing.