# Real-time question updates not working correctly

Tags: support, live-refresh

I am having a problem using the feature that allows real time updates to the question feed on the Stack Exchange sites. For example, when I have selected the JavaScript tag on Stack Overflow, this happens:

[image: No message shown before refresh]

And **not until I refresh** will the new question appear:

[image: Refreshed view]

I have tried waiting a few minutes for the new question message to appear, but *it never does*. Interestingly, on other Stack Exchange sites like Super User, the feature works perfectly using the same browser:

[image: Update message on Super User]

I am aware of the questions which address this issue like those below:

- [When the feature was first released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox)
- [A relevant question with a similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144298/stack-overflow-is-not-getting-refreshed-automatically)
- [And another relevant question with a similar problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276200/do-you-need-to-refresh-pages-after-a-while-to-continue-getting-live-updates)

I know there are **no automatic question updates on the front page** of Stack Overflow, which is why I have shown that I have the JavaScript tag open by going to the tags button from the homepage and then clicking on JavaScript.

I am using Safari 9.1.1, and I have tested to make sure web sockets works [here](http://websocketstest.com/); plus the feature is working on the other sites *with the same browser*, so I don't think it is a problem with my computer (or any Anti-virus applications installed).

Is there something I am missing in my approach to get the real time message through tags I am looking at, or is it a bug in the site? Is anyone else experiencing similar difficulties?

Comment: It works now :)

Comment: Yes, I have just barely crossed the threshold. :)

Comment: @iRove108: Barely? You overachieved by not less than 10%! ;)

Comment: @honk: Technically true.  Your answer makes me wonder what other "features" you gain access to at higher reputations that _aren't_ listed in the privileges page.  These "secret privileges" seem to be like hidden gems.

Comment: @iRove108: There are no more hidden privileges that I know of. But I still discover each week something that I didn't know before. Just read a few Meta posts every day and you will learn a lot ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, real-time notifications for new questions are a privilege granted at 30 reputation, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322824/2675154) by [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded). This is due to performance reasons and does not apply to other Stack Exchange sites (at least currently).

You currently have 23 reputation on Stack Overflow, so you need to earn just 7 further reputation to get access to the live updates.

Unfortunately, this privilege is not mentioned on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). However, there is a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324061/2675154) by [JonasCz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4428462/jonascz) to put it there.

Comment: Thank you, I would have never guessed this was the issue.  The people over at Stack Overflow really should document this _somewhere_ for confused users.  I should not have to sift through questions/answers just to find out that a feature mentioned requires a set amount of reputation...I guess there isn't much we can do about it though.

Comment: Publicly consumable documentation for the SE interface is overall very poor.

Comment: Real-time notifications seem also sometimes to forget the job when on a slow internet connection.

Comment: It's okay, they're creating ["Documentation"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow/303981), which I'm sure will solve all problems!